# Macbook pro for magento front-end development?

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio, macbook

I am magento front-end developer and I have question about best choice of macbook for work.

My work consists of:

- magento 2 - 49% of time
- magento pwa studio - 49% of time
- magento 1 - 2% of time

Currently I work on HP laptop on ubuntu, which work almost perfect, but sometimes it is painful for front-end work.
I also have experience with windows and open-server, also was quite painful.
So currently I want to switch at macbook pro for better balance and usability for front-end developent.

One of my colleague work on macbook pro 2019 intel core i-9 (16) and very happy with that laptop.
I can't decide which would be better choice, macbook pro 2019 intel core i-9 (16)  or new macbook m1 pro/max (16)

I heard there is a lot of problems with magento, and docker and vagrant...
What do you think? Maybe some one has expirience with new macbook m1 pro/max and magento 2?

Comment: Almost all servers which host Magento websites, use Linux. So in my opinion, Linux (any variant) would be better than Windows/Mac. Its just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about your workflow this question can't be answered.

E.g. are you using Docker, Vagrant or a different platform? Or just local installation.
Are you building the frontend during deployment or are you committing CSS and JS to the repository. Or are you not using a deployment workflow and just uploading the sources via FTP?

If your colleage is happy with the choice of his hardware, why are you asking us? Your colleage will have a better knowledge about the troubles and possible pitfalls in your daily business.